# Doctrine add subquery value to entity virtual property

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, jmsserializerbundle

Is it possible to put subquery value to an entity virtual property?

```
SELECT o, od, (SELECT count(f.id) FROM AppBundle:Feedback f WHERE f.order = o.id AND f.from = :provider) isFeedbackAdded
FROM  AppBundle:Order o
LEFT JOIN o.detail od
WHERE o.provider = :provider
AND   o.created > :date
ORDER BY o.created DESC
```

I want to add `isFeedbackAdded` value to Order entity virtual property, so when it automatically serialize it, it shows fine with order object.

Answer (score 1):

one way would be to create an event subscriber and subscribe to the `postSerialize` event.

Define your service using the `jms_serializer.event_subscriber` tag

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.subscriber.oder_serialization_subscriber:
        class: AppBundle\Subscriber\OrderSerializationSubscriber
        tags:
            - { name: jms_serializer.event_subscriber }
```

and create the subscriber class

```
# AppBundle/Subscriber/OrderSerializationSubscriber.php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Subscriber;

use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\ObjectEvent;
use JMS\Serializer\GenericSerializationVisitor;
use AppBundle\Entity\Order;

class OrderSerializationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            array(
                'event' => 'serializer.post_serialize',
                'method' => 'postSerialize',
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param ObjectEvent $event
     */
    public function postSerialize( ObjectEvent $event ) {

        /** @var Order $order */
        $order = $event->getObject();

        if ( ! $order instanceof Order ) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var GenericSerializationVisitor $visitor */
        $visitor = $event->getVisitor();

        // fetch feed data from repository or directly on the object if a (bidirectional) relation exists
        $feedback = $order->hasFeedback();

        // set virtual property
        $visitor->addData( 'isFeedBackAdded', $feedback );

    }
}
```

Comment: Order entity never gets `isFeedbackAdded` or `hasFeedback` because that is part of a subquery. you can elaborate how I can pass from the array to object I guess. Following is example https://gist.github.com/iBasit/f0b9e94575f901514a5a73c8ae1f4b81

Comment: @Basit remove your subquery from the main query, inject the entity manager / repository into the subscriber and fire the query up there to get the value you need to add.

Comment: It does work, but it is creating N+1 query problem, how can we keep the subquery and still do it? so it does not hit many queries on list view.